# how to apply a few styles properties depends on condition styled-components

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, styled-components

Is it possible to apply a few styles of properties at once?

```
const Button = styled.div`
  color: blue;
  opacity: 0.6;
  background-color: #ccc;
`
```

I need to pass active property, which will affect color, opacity, background-color. How can I apply styles for the active button at once instead of declaring conditions for each property?

```
const Button = styled.div`
  color: ${props.active ? 'green' : 'blue'};
  opacity: ${props.active ? 1 : 0.6};
  background-color: : ${props.active ? 'white' : '#ccc'};
```

Answer (score 2):

Create two classes and switch that classes according to property `active`

For example -

**CSS**

```
.activeClass{
  color:  green;
  opacity:  1 ;
  background-color:white;
}

.inactiveClass{
  color: blue;
  opacity:  0.6;
  background-color: #ccc;
 }
```

**in Render**

```
<button id="mybtn"  className={this.props.active ? 'activeClass' : 'inactiveClass'} >mybutton</button>
```

[See working example here](https://jsfiddle.net/aalok123/1vgscLpz/7/)

Comment: OP asks about styled-components (css-in-js).

Comment: @DennisVash but it still remains a good practice and comes handy for maintenance. It is a good advice that deserves to be explained in the answer.

Comment: Editing classNames in css-in-js is very uncommon practice.

Answer (score 2):

A common approach is a conditional rendering of CSS blocks with `css` API:

```
const first = css`
  color: green;
  opacity: 1;
  background-color: white;
`;

const second = css`
  color: blue;
  opacity: 0.6;
  background-color: #ccc;
`;

const Button = styled.div`
  ${({ active }) => (active ? first : second)}
`;

const App = () => {
  const [active, trigger] = useReducer(p => !p, false);
  return (
    <Button active={active} onClick={() => trigger()}>
      Press Me
    </Button>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit damp-sky-93y2d]

Or using common utilities like [`swithProp` from `styled-tools`](https://github.com/diegohaz/styled-tools#switchprop):

```
import styled, { css } from "styled-components";
import { switchProp, prop } from "styled-tools";

const Button = styled.button`
  font-size: ${switchProp(prop("size", "medium"), {
    small: prop("theme.sizes.sm", "12px"),
    medium: prop("theme.sizes.md", "16px"),
    large: prop("theme.sizes.lg", "20px")
  }, prop("theme.sizes.md", "16px"))};
  ${switchProp("theme.kind", {
    light: css`
      color: LightBlue;
    `,
    dark: css`
      color: DarkBlue;
    `
  }, css`color: black;`)}
`;

<Button size="large" theme={{ kind: "light" }} />
```

Comment: There is no need to use `css` with static styles here, you can just leave it out.

Comment: I don't understand what "leave it out" means

Comment: Drop `css` in `first`,`second` styles and only use template literals, that's what I meant.

Comment: Can you make an example (you have a sandbox attached in answer)

Comment: That's not a good idea, as you don't get autocomplete and linting in this way (it's just a string).

Comment: Ah, I see, good point. I think, the lost DX doesn't warrant a saved import for `css`. +1 for your clarification